# deny direct access of file but need to download in href tag - htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I had the files in folder `test`

and I denied for accessing the directory from this in .htaccess (www.example .com),
`Options All -Indexes` but if i type the link directly in browser means the files are easily downloadable `www.example.com/test/sample.pdf`.

In customer.php file I gave that link in href tag `<a href="www.example.com/test/sample.pdf" download>`.

I need to block the direct access and allowed it in href tag in `www.example.com/customer.php`

Comment: I'm curious: how exactly does direct access differ from following a link in your mind? What is your interpretation of the hypertext model?

Comment: i denied the test directory using .htaccess which is located in www.example.com

Comment: @Bullet, that doesn't necessarily prevent people from accessing files in it.

Comment: @PedroLobito
`Options All -Indexes 
  <Directory ~ "/test">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Directory>`

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below,

```
Options -Indexes #remove listing

<Files ~ ".*\.(pdf|exe|gz|zip)">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1 #allow from localhost
</Files>
```

Comment: Im not only having .pdf, .exe,.gz,.zip, etc are there

Comment: Do you want deny direct access to all files?

Comment: yes but in `<a href="www.example.com/test/photo.png" download>` i need to download

Comment: not working. after applied this code, when access www.example.com itself is not working

Comment: My .htacess and php files are in `subfolder` (ie. www.example.com/subfolder), but I have the files in `test` folder (ie. www.example.com/subfolder/test ). I denied direct access of test folder using `Options All -Indexes` in htaccess of `subfolder` but when I used your code the total `subfolder` directory itself denied. I need only the content of `test` folder deny by direct access but accessible through href tag in `somefile.php` of `subfolder`

Comment: Are you not able to use it in test directory if able please give it a try in test.

Comment: I tried in test directory, it blocks direct download but also i need to be download with `<href>` in `subfolder/customer.php`

Comment: is it the right way i'm using `<Files ~ ".*">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from www.example.com/subfolder/customer.php
</Files>`